# Is this chill haze?

Tags: fermentation, all-grain, chilling, biab, partial-mash

Did a BIAB IPA last night and this is what the wort looks like. The cooling method was an ice bath that took 45 minutes.

Is this chill haze?

Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not chill haze. It is a mixture of yeast, hops, and proteins that form from the hot and cold break. I agree it looks like you have some Starsan in your batch. I learned early swap the blow off tube for a airlock before you cold crash.

Once active fermentation starts you will see all kinds of floating yeast and stiring going on. It's really my favorite part of brewing other than drinking my beer.

After fermenting is complete, I would then cold crash it to below 40 and all of that sediment will drop to the bottom and make a firm cake. You beer should bee pretty clear. If your really want it to be clear then fine with gelatin and you will be very impressed.

Comment: Fermentation is moving nicely. Still really cloudy, though.

Comment: It will be until you fine it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like starsan on top that siphoned into the fermentor from a Blow off bottle. This will happen if the wort drops temp faster than co2 is produced.

Chill haze happens in the finished beer at serving temps, and is easy to identify by comparing a warm glass of it to a cold pour.

Comment: Thanks. That's what it looked like right after transferring to the fermenter. Really cloudy but hoping for it to clear up a bit.

Comment: @mstrom it's going to look a lot worse during fermentation. When fermentation is complete is when you give the real attention to clairity. But I'm concerned about the white layer of liquid, can you account for it?

Comment: @mstrom it's difficult to suck it off the top, but pretty easy to get the beer out from under it. I would get it separated before fermentation starts or it will mix quickly

Comment: I'd bet that light difference is just the refraction of light coming through the beer differently.  Its right at the "rib" in what appears to be a better bottle.  I'd find it nearly impossible that someone racked wort into an inch of StarSan and the StarSan somehow floated on top perfectly like that. Especially if the thing has been moved at some point.

Comment: @brewchez he confirmed it was starsan. Starsan floats if it's sucked in from a siphon caused by temp drop in the fermentor.